# How to remove characters from an array item?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function which generate random poker hand and after that I want to delete all the suits and just leave numbers to the array. What is the easiest way to do that? I have tried different things without any good results.

For example array could be something like this:

```
test = ["5♥","7♦","6♠","9♥","10♣"];
```

but I want it to be like this:

```
test = ["5","7","6","9","10"];
```

I wanna emphasize that in this case I have no idea what kind of array it would be when the function generate the array and delete the suits.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: *I have tried different things without any good results.* Include those different things that you tried in your question, so people can help you better and faster. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and use `slice()` to remove the last element of string.

```js
const test = ["5♥","7♦","6♠","9♥","10♣"];

const res = test.map(x => x.slice(0,-1));

console.log(res)
```

Comment: should really be mapping a replace onto it however for a more versatile solution.

Comment: @Hemoi Consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 3):

You could remove the last character of each string.

```js
let test = ["5♥","7♦","6♠","9♥","10♣"];
let out = test.map(a => a.slice(0, -1));
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex ,

```js
let test = ["5♥","7♦","6♠","9♥","10♣"];

console.log(test.map(str => str.replace(/.$/, '')));
```

Comment: No need to use constructor.`test.map(str => str.replace(/.$/, ''))` will be fine.